# Getting nearby counties in openstreetmaps

Tags: maps, openstreetmap

Is there any way to get nearby counties for a given GPS coordinates? for example: 
[link](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse/?lat=50.993284524681954&lon=8.628602027893066&zoom=22&format=json&json_callback=_l_geocoder_0)

The above query will return exact county for sure. but I want to have other counties which are nearby as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please be more accurate. Which for programming language and API do you want to use, or makes it no difference ?

Comment: Overpass API with the `around` query is your friend.

Comment: Hi @Manuel I am using this in my angularjs application.